# Can anyone tell me what an exam paper is asking for here?

Tags: java, loops, methods, static, boolean

I have a practice exam question from my professor. Here is the code:

```
public static boolean majority(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c) {
  return ( a && b) || (a && c) || (b && c);
}
```

And the instructions say:

> State a legal statement to call or activate or use the above method.

And on the paper there's not much space to write, so... it's kind of confusing. What exactly is my professor looking for? And quite honestly, I'm not good with booleans and my textbook offers no good examples on them, any guidance here?

Comment: i guess he just wants you to mention something like `boolean a = YourClass.majoirity(true,true,true);` or the same in an `if` statment.

Comment: *"And the instructions say: State a legal statement to call or activate or use the above method."* That's a very convoluted way to say "Write a valid statement that calls this method." So: How do you call a method that accepts three boolean parameters?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming as defined in the [help center](/help/on-topic). It's about the meaning of an exam question.

Comment: Is it `a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`?  If so, it applies to StackOverflow @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @RossDrew: Read the three bullet points prior to that which are joined to it with "and."

Comment: `a specific programming problem, and` ... `a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`

Language used by programmers is as much a "programming problem" as, say, how to pass a variable length array.  Questions such as "What is big data?", "What's the difference between IaaS and PaaS?" are no different (other than level) to "What is meant by a 'legal statement to activate a method'?"

Comment: @RossDrew: Meh, whatever. I don't think it's on-topic (nor do at least a couple of other people). You do. That's fine.

Answer (score 1):

You want  "**a legal statement** (Java statement that is legal and compiles) **to call or activate** (make use of)  **the above method**".  So...

```
majority(true, false, true);
```

but it's a static method so if you are calling it from outside the class, you need to include the class name

```
TheClassName.majority(true, false, true);
```

You could get a little more advanced and use it in a statement

```
System.out.println( "The majority of the inputs are " + majority(true, false, true))
```